# How to pass structure from/to function that initialize structure?

Tags: c

I saw many ways of how the structure is initialized in function, two ways that I remember are...

#### 1. Return mem. allocated structure pointer from function and pass NULL from the function if some error happend.

```
struct Type* type_init(<struct arguments>){
    struct Type* type = calloc(1, sizeof(Type));
    //... complex initialization process...
    return type;
}

int main(){
    struct Type* type = type_init(...);
}
```

#### 2. Pass address of already allocated structure to function arguments and return operation result.

```
int type_init(struct Type* type, <struct arguments>){
    //... complex initialization process...
    return result;
}

int main(){
    struct Type type = {};
    type_init(&type, ...);
}
```

For me the second method is better since user can create struct on the stack and than pass address of pointer to the function...

My question is:

1. Is there a preferred (standard) way to pass structure from and to a function?
2. When to pick the right method base on the use cases?
3. Is there downsides to any of the (listed/unlisted) methods?

Thank you for your time, and all the best!

Comment: There's no hidden knowledge here. (1) forces a heap allocation, (2) forces user to allocate the struct even on failure.

Comment: There's conflicting conventions around this. The fundamental issue is that there's usually two things that need to be returned: the object that was created, or some error data on why the operation wasn't successful. But C doesn't have exceptions, and you can only return one thing from a function in C. So the question becomes: which value do you privilege by being the return value, and which do you relegate to the out-param: the error value, or the intended value?

Comment: Of course you can create a `TypeOrError` value, which is discriminated union to house either a value of `Type`, or an error, but writing that requires hand-rolling an `enum` (to store the "tag"), a `union` (between the two types), and a struct (which packages the tag and union together). It's a lot of boilerplate, and the lack of generics means you need to repeat this for every type you want to support similar to `Type`.

Comment: Please note #2 does not rule out #1; you can later decide to create a wrapper function that calls `calloc` followed by `type_init`, thereby implementing #1 on top of #2.

Answer (score 1):

Use 1st approach in general.

Prefer the 2nd approach when the object is small and of a numeric flavor.

---

This first approach allows for [information hiding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_hiding) and is similar to `FILE *, fopen(), fclose()` ...

`struct Type* type_init(<struct arguments>)` allows the caller to *only* know that `struct Type*` exist and *nothing* about the `struct` members.  This is *good*.

This hiding helps with large programs as it keeps untangled various parts of code.

This [divide and conquer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide-and-conquer_algorithm) approach allows the caller to use `UJ` as a totally abstract thing, much like `FILE`.  Do you know or care what members are in `FILE`?

Consider the clean example below.  *All* internal members, allocation,  maintenance of `UJ` is handled elsewhere, likely in some `UJ.c` file that implements the various `UF_...()` functions.

```
// Maybe this part in a UJ.h file
typedef struct UJ UJ;

UJ *UJ_init(int a, const char *b);
void UJ_uninit(UJ *state);

int UJ_get_a(const UJ *state);
const char *UJ_get_b(const UJ *state);
bool UJ_done(const UJ *state);
void UJ_increment(UJ *state);

bool UJ_iserror(const UJ *state);
const char *UJ_error(const UJ *state);
///////////

// Example usage
int main() {
  UJ *uj = UJ_init(rand(), "Hello World");
  while (!UJ_done(uj)) {
    printf("%d %s\n", UJ_get_a(uj), UJ_get_b(uj));
    UJ_increment(uj);
  }
  if (UJ_iserror(uj)) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: %s\n", UJ_error(uj));
  }

  UJ_uninit(uj);
}
```

---

The second approach is useful for small user-defined *numeric* or trivial types.  Example: [quaternion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion).  Here there is little to *hide*.

```
struct {
  double a,b,c,d;
} quaternion;

bool quaternion_init(quaternion *q, int a, int b, int c, int d);
quaternion quaternion_add(quaternion qa, quaternion qa);
quaternion quaternion_mul(quaternion qa, quaternion qa);
double quaternion_abs(quaternion qa);
```

Comment: Small is somewhat "relative", as you can properly handle fairly "large" structs with method 2 and a 4M stack (even a 1K struct could be considered "large" in some settings). Hard to give a rule of thumb, but only that the larger and more involved the program, the more choice would moderate to No. 1, except that trivial structs would still be more efficiently handled under No. 2.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Yes, "relative" is a judgment call.  My recommended threshold of _small_ is if the passing of the object by value is reasonable vs. the usual passing by address.  `quaternion` is about at that threshold.  In C, numeric types are used by value.  Most other library functions pass by address.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin A 3rd, sneaky way is to pass by reference.  C does have that in a limited way: `typedef int obj[1];`.  (Shades of horror, typedef-ing an array!)  Consider `foo(obj)`.  The receiving code of `void foo(obj a);` is formally receiving a _pointer_, yet the caller can view the argument passing as by reference.

Comment: That's a good proposition that just might fit the bill in some cases. (and I suspect it can be found more than once in the kernel code, along with other similar witchcraft `:)`

Answer (score 0):

Those are just two different approaches, there is no standard (to my knowledge) way to do it. I've seen both approaches a lot.

Both have different (dis)advantages.

1. Approach:

- (In the general case,) caller has no knowledge about how/what memory was allocated for the struct. That makes a corresponding `type_deinit` or `type_destroy` function that frees allocated ressources almost necessary.
- It's difficult to return errors. Well, not really difficult, but in my opinion not as convenient. You can ofcourse return `NULL` when an error occured. You can pass a pointer to an `int` or whatever that receives an error code. You can do as Alexander suggested in the comments.
- You can use such an init function to chain to other functions. Say function `a` returns a pointer to a `type` struct, `b` takes a `type` struct pointer as an argument. You can do `b(a(*some arguments that a needs*))`. May be desirable, may not be. Depends on wether or not `a` can fail and wether or not `b` can accept invalid parameters.
- Simple to use. Callee returns either a valid object or `NULL`

2. Approach:

- Caller is responsible for memory allocation and deallocation and has full control about that (can be advantage or disadvantage). May allow caller do do some optimizations (say caller needs 10.000 `type` structs. Caller could just allocate memory for all of those with a single malloc/calloc call).
- Return value is free to be used to return an error code.
- Not as simple to use. Caller needs to manage ressources.
- Can't chain to other functions.

Those are the point i could think of ad-hoc, im sure there are more.

When you pick which methods is basically up to you and the specific usecase. I strongly prefer the second method.

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no officially "standard" method to use (unless you are enforced by some coding standard in your project). However, some methods fit better for some use cases, while other not.

For example, the second method you listed allows the programmer to keep the `struct` on the stack, and this has a lot of pros: can be used in environments where dynamic allocation is forbidden; your code is more predictable (no `malloc()`, no time-unpredictable syscall, no possible failure). But you cannot use this approach in some cases (e.g.: the `struct` has to be dynamically-allocated because it is part of a linked list or whatever).

Yet another approach is to return the `struct` by value and not as a heap-allocated pointer (but it's not always possible to do that).

The method you choose is highly dependent on the context of the program (i.e.: what the program should do, what it's allowed to do, what the `struct` will be used for, etc.), but all methods are basically "correct" to use (when they satisfy the program's requirements).

As a matter of personal taste, I use the second method more often, because this way I don't have to do useless dynamic allocations. I use the first method, instead, in case the `struct` has to be heap-allocated.